# Eliminar filas con campos repetidos

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo 2 tablas que hacen referencia entre ellas por un campo `name`

Esta vendría a ser la estructura de las dos tablas:

```
Versions { productCategory, version, name }
Products {product, category, name}
```

Para la tabla `Versions`, por cada valor de `name` puede haber varias versiones:

```
"test-one", "v1", "test-one-v1"
"test-two", "v0", "test-one-v2"
"test-one", "v0", "test-one-v0"
```

Pero solo una de esas versiones o ninguna aparecerá en `Products` para cada producto

```
"test", "one", "test-one-v1"
```

Es decir que para `name` "test-one" puede haber 10 versiones pero solo 1 estará ligada a una entrada "test", "one" en `Products`

La respuesta que espero es algo así:

```
"test-one", "v1", "test", "one"
"test-two", "v0", null, null
```

Pero hoy estoy algo espeso y no consigo sacarlo..

Con esta query

```
SELECT p.product, p.category, v.name
FROM
    Versions v
    LEFT JOIN Products p ON v.index_version::text = p.write_index::text;
```

Saco la siguiente info

```
"test-one", "v0", null, null
"test-one", "v1", "test", "one"
"test-two", "v0", null, null
```

Pero no consigo descartar test-one-v0 de la ecuación.
He pensado en hacer un GROUPBY productCategory y concatenar product para obtener esos datos pero necesito mas datos en esas tablas para generar una vista...

Otra idea es hacer un UNION pero tampoco tengo claro como descartar de uno los registros que ya tengo en el otro...

Answer (score 0):

Lo he conseguido haciendo lo siguiente:

```
-- Obtener todos los registros que están relacionados

SELECT p.product, p.category, v.otherField
FROM
    Versions v
    Products p
WHERE
    v.index_version::text = p.write_index::text;

UNION

-- Obtener los registros que no tienen ninguna relación con Product

SELECT DISTINCT
    UPPER(SPLIT_PART(productCategory, '-', 1)), -- product
    UPPER(SPLIT_PART(productCategory, '-', 2)), -- category
    null
FROM
    Versions
WHERE
   productCategory NOT IN (
       SELECT SPLIT_PART(name, '-', 1) || '-' || SPLIT_PART(name, '-', 2)
       FROM Products)
;
```

La parte rara está en el WHERE de la última consulta. Ya que cogemos el `name` que sería test-one-v1 y guardamos solo la primera parte. Y de esa forma descartamos todos los registros que existen en Products...

No estoy muy satisfecho con la solución pero es una solución. Si alguien tiene una mejor soy todo oídos.